# Convert time in microseconds to minutes and seconds

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, time, ffmpeg

My iPhone app uses FFMPeg for decoding/playing an audio file.

I'm successfully getting the current time in microseconds from the appropriate FFMPeg function, but I'm not being able to convert it to minutes and seconds (MM:SS).

This is my code to display an `NSString` containing the time; `getFFMPEGtime` is the time in microseconds:

```
 self.currentAudioTime = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02d:%02d",
                                (int) getFFMPEGtime / (int)1000000,
                                (int) getFFMPEGtime % 1000000];
```

It seems that the time in minutes is okay, but the seconds are messed up. What's the proper way to convert microseconds to minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd argue that your time in seconds is probably right and your time in minutes is most likely wrong.

`(int) getFFMPEGtime / (int)1000000` is giving you total **seconds**

To get `MM:SS`, you need to do the following:

```
self.currentAudioTime = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02d:%02d",
                                (int) getFFMPEGtime / (int)60000000,
                                (int) ((getFFMPEGtime % 60000000)/1000000)];
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, but It didn't work. I'm getting a negative time on minutes and seconds and the time in seconds is decreasing.

Comment: +1, now it's correct! Also similar to my answer. No worries Brian, it happens. But I don't really think that was causing the error the OP described.

Comment: Brian and Anne are right, but I'm still getting a wrong result. NSLog is showing the correct time in microseconds, but some how the final result on the NSString is giving me a higher number than the right one. This time is dynamic, gets updated, it's not the total time. I'll keep checking and thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 6):

Code:

```
int microseconds = 59434225;
int seconds = microseconds / 1000000;
NSString * result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",seconds/60,seconds%60];
```

Output:

```
63434225 -> 01:03
59434225 -> 00:59
```

Answer (score 1):

This is math, if you have µs, and one minute has 60s, divide your number by 60000000 and you have your minutes.

The remainder of dividing your number by 60e6 is in µseconds, so divide that by 1e6 to get the seconds.

Example:

Given 123456789 µs, you have:

1. 123456789 / 60e6 = **2 minutes**
2. ((123456789 % 60e6) / 1e6) = **3.45 seconds**